# Не работает смена картинки в плавающем меню

Tags: javascript, css, css3, css-animation

Использую на сайте скрипт плавающего меню и хочу что-бы в нем были кнопки с заменой картинки на них. По отдельности `hover` работает, а в этом меню нет. Можете помочь его допилить?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
    $('.fixmenu').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $('.fixmenu').removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000%;
}

.menus {
  width: 169px;
}

.menus:hover {
  background: url(https://img.fonwall.ru/o/89/voda_reka_goryi_sneg_ozero.jpg);
}

.fixmenu {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 95;
}

.fixmenu.fixed {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  margin-bottom: -55px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 95;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fadeInUp 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixmenu">fixmenu
  <div class="menus">menus
    <a href="#yak1"><img width="100" height="100" src="http://rusmama.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/nature-144.jpg" />Кнопка</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Каков должен быть  окончательный результат? ничего не понятно

Comment: @Air, Должно быть фиксированное меню, которое появляется при скроллинге вниз. В этом меню должна быть кнопка, которая меняет картинку при наведение.

Comment: У тебя и так все работает

Comment: при чем тут тег `<a>`, нужна кнопка используй `button`...

Comment: просто все криво и неправильно... тут все надо переписывать... с нуля

Comment: нет высоты ни у одного элемента

Comment: @Air, гениальные ответы, жалко что бесполезные. Зачем мне высоты, это маленький кусочек кода. При редактирование я добавил главный див "сон" с высотой 3000 рх, но вы походу его изменили. И у вас также не работает скрытие картинки, А как сделать правильно не сказали.

Comment: может быть [ТАК](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/mGaWBN) надо ?

Comment: @Никита Фаст, отличный пример, но мне нужно событие "hover" или "mouseover/out" - кликать на кнопку мне не нужно. Подставил событие mouseover/out в ваш пример, картинка стала мигать)